# how to remove the last characters of a variable in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove a file's last characters that it's name is somedigits plus `.py` and plus `.BR` like `0001.py.BR` or `0005.py.BR` and remove the `.BR` from the string.

I tried this code

```
import os
x = input("")
os.rename(x, x[7])
```

but it sometimes don't work for some file that their names are larger like `00001.py.BR` it renames it to `00001.p` so is there a way that I just do like this `x - ".BR"`.

Comment: will this work for you ? `os.rename(x, x[:-3])`

Answer (score 1):

if you talking about file path,

then use `os.path.splitext()`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('00001.py.BR')[0]
'00001.py'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in **split** function like this:

```
import os
x=input("")
x_new = x.split(".BR")[0]
os.rename(x, x_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, check the standard [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

old_path = Path(input(""))
if old_path.suffix == '.BR':
    old_path.rename(old_path.stem)
else:
    print('this is not a .BR file')
```